# Cant read CSV Data(excpected different n of fields)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Im trying to read a CSV file that contains raw data that I want to sanitize.

If i try to run this file:

```
#1)Read CSV File
file = 'data/opel_corsa_01.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file,error_bad_lines=False, engine ='python')
```

I get the following error:

```
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 7, saw 7
```

I think its because some columns dont have any data in them?

After looking online, i saw various solutions but didnt seem to fix my problem.
Such as:

```
#1)Read CSV File
file = 'data/opel_corsa_01.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file,error_bad_lines=False, engine ='python')
```

Would anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Can you give an example of the data please

Comment: what does your csv looks like? show at least top 10-15 rows and ideally some rows from the end. Is it possible that you have rows with commas in the last column and the lasy field in that columns in sot quoted?

Comment: Sorry i didnt know how to show the data as it is so messy, so i wrapped text to show you. its just because the columns are random but the values are separated by ; which i then have to combine by.

Comment: Please, don't post images of code, errors, input, output, etc. Copy/paste as text. In this case - open the csv file in editor like Notepad and copy the content, not in Excel or images of it. Even from this poor picture is visible that you have semi-colon as separator, while default one is comma.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, but when i select the cells and copy, after pasting it, it pastes it like this image. Ah i see, so its  because of the semi-colon, so i just need to replace it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to specify the separator? and also encoding:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=";", encoding="latin1", error_bad_lines=False, engine ='python')
```

separator: from your image, it appears that you have ";" as separator of fields

encoding: `latin1` is kind of the most generous.